# Typescript - is there a way to do like 'new functionName()' like in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am wondering if I have a function declared as:

```
function foo(){
  var x = 10;
}
```

How do I use something in javascript like:

```
var foo1 = new foo();// In javascript to create an object type of a function
var xOfFoo = foo1.x;
```

to create an object type of a function, and get access to the properties of it in typescript?

Comment: Typescript is a superset of javascript. So nothing stops you if you want to do what you explicit wrote, in a typescript file.

Comment: Unless you have `noImplicitAny` set to `true`, because `new foo()` will have implicit type `any` unless it's a `class`

Comment: @MiguelLattuada I think in typescript the keyword `new` only supports constructor signature of a class, but it is not the case in javascript

Comment: @slezica where can I set the property `noImplicitAny`?

Comment: In the `compilerOptions` section of `tsconfig.json`, or passing `--noImplicitAny` to `tsc`. I don't know if it's the best solution though, perhaps you could define a `type Foo` with the properties you expect, then `let x: Foo = Object.create(foo.prototype); foo.call(x)`

Comment: const foo1 = () => { console.log("Foo!"; };
        foo1();

Comment: @MattSearles with this, can I still access the properties inside `foo1()`?

Comment: @LeoLi what is wrong by using class ?

Comment: You've edited your question... even in JavaScript `foo1.x` would not resolve to anything because the function `foo()` declares a *local* variable named `x`, not a *property*.  You may be looking for `this.x = 10;` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in TypeScript. In this case, `this` will refer to the scope of the function, because the function declaration is not within a class.

```
function foo()
{
    this.x = 10;
}

var instance = new foo();
console.log(instance.x);
```

Comment: But I don’t think you could use ‘new’ for declaring a function

Comment: Sure you can :) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20foo()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20instance%20%3D%20new%20foo()%3B%0D%0Aalert(instance.x)%3B